# Работа с xinetd. ( Запуск переданных из PHP сокета команд )

Tags: сокеты, php, сокет

**Задача:**
Из PHP передать команды удаленной машинке и выполнить их на это машинке. ( *При этом, во время выполнения команд, PHP скрипт не должен висеть запущенным*. )

Решено было использовать **сокеты** и демон **xinetd** для того, что бы слушать tcp порт, и при открытии соединения через этот порт запускать bash скрипт.

Проблема заключается в следующем: У меня очень смутные представления о том как использовать xinetd (Правда уже почти 10 часов сижу читаю различную инфу по этой теме). Поэтому я не могу запустить даже тестовый скрипт.

**xinetd** установил.

**xinetd.conf:**

```
# Simple configuration file for xinetd
#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/

defaults
{
    # Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
    # and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
    # log_type = SYSLOG daemon info
    instances           = 60
    log_type            = FILE /var/log/servicelog
    log_on_success      = HOST PID
    log_on_failure      = HOST RECORD
    only_from           = 127.0.0.1
    only_from           = localhost .mysite.local
    disabled            = tftp
    cps                 = 60 10
}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

В директорию **/etc/xinetd.d**, положил файл **testservice**, с содержанием:

```
service testservice
{
    disable             = no
    socket_type         = stream
    protocol            = tcp
    port                = 5900
    log_on_success      += USERID
    log_on_failure      += USERID
    server              = /test-ssh-php/testservicesh
    user                = root
    instances           = UNLIMITED
    wait                = no
    log_type            = FILE /test-ssh-php/testservicesh_log
}
```

В **/etc/services** добавил в самый конец:

```
# My Services:
testservice        5900/tcp
```

Содержание **/test-ssh-php/testservicesh** (*Который является значением **server** в **service testservice***), другими словами содержание bash скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "connection received";

mkdir /test-ssh-php/gg
```

PHP скрипт, который соединяется:

```
   $errno;
    $errstr;
    $fp = fsockopen( "127.0.0.1", 5900, $errno, $errstr);
    var_dump($fp);
    if ( !$fp ) 
    {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
    } 
    else 
    {
        fputs( $fp, "Test From PHP" );
        while( !feof( $fp ) ) {
            echo fgets ($fp, 4096);
        }
        fclose( $fp );
    }
```

var_dump в PHP скрипте выдает: **resource(2) of type (stream)**. На сколько я понимаю, соединение произошло. Но кроме этого ничего больше не произошло! Вобще ничего!

Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: В /var/log/servicelog никаких записей?
chmod +x для скрипта сделали?

А проверять IMHO удобней telnet-ом или nc (он же netcat).

Для проверки настройки самого xinetd качните какой-нибудь известный сервис (например finger [пример здесь](http://community.thimbl.net/discussion/93/installing-xinetdfinger-on-debian./p1))

Comment: "chmod +x для скрипта сделали?": Да

"В /var/log/servicelog никаких записей?": этого файла не существует впринцепе, но я случайно заглянул в файл с похожим названием, в той же папке, и увидел вот что:

Apr  5 00:48:14 debianvirtual1 xinetd[1041]: Bad log_on_failure flag: RECORD [file=/etc/xinetd.conf] [line=13]
Apr  5 00:48:14 debianvirtual1 xinetd[1041]: A fatal error was encountered while parsing the default section. xinetd will exit.
Apr  5 00:48:14 debianvirtual1 xinetd[1041]: Exiting...

Comment: Про netcat почитаю на досуге.

"finger": Что-то я вобще ничего не нашел по этому поводу. Что это вобще? Для чего используется?

Comment: @Flasko finger давно запрещается в системах по причине безопасности. Поэтом птица редкая. Закоментарьте это log_on_failure и посмотрите, что получится. А то описание xinetd.conf я читал много лет назад.

Comment: Закоментировал. Сам сервис xinetd запустился. /var/log/servicelog не появилось(. 

Попробовал присоединиться из PHP скрипта, опять ничего не произошло. Но теперь появился файл /test-ssh-php/testservicesh_log. Там было написано: 13/4/5@20:29:56: START: testservice pid=1083 from=10.0.2.2
13/4/5@20:29:56: FAIL: testservice address

Тогда я добавил 10.0.2.2 в only_from.
Соединение произошло! Но почему-то PHP скрипт оооочень долго все это делает.(около 20 секунд). Это так и должно быть?

Comment: И еще вопросик. Домен с которого я произвожу соединение http://mysite.local/test.php

В настройках only_from стоит .mysite.local, но без 10.0.2.2 в only_from меня не пустило! Неправильные настройки? Как сделать что-бы с домена пускало, вне зависимости IP